# Why is my While loop infinite

Tags: loops, while-loop, infinite

This while loop is giving me trouble as it simply will not stop, I'm trying to update elem to eventually be larger then char by using an exponent i but that simply doesn't happen and was wondering if there were any solutions.

```
i = 0
char = 20
elem = 2
while elem < char:
    elem**i
    i += 1
```

Comment: `elem` and `char` are never changing in your loop, so `elem < char` is always true. So the loop is infinite. `elim**i` doesn't change the value of `elim`.

Comment: Also, the first pass through, elem is raised to the 0 power.  Even if you assigned the value to elem, it would become 1, and subsequent iterations would raise 1^i, which would never exceed 1 for any positive value of i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not changing the value of `elem`, you are just repeatedly calculating `elem**i`, so when you compare `elem` to `char` it is always the same result. The simplest solution is to compare `elem**i` to `char`.

You probably meant:

```
while elem**i < char:
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying to a variable with zero value